# Modify Case Date/Time Opened Field on Upload

Tags: case, data-loader, datetime, bulk-api, case-object

I'm trying to import some historical case data into our SalesForce account either through Bulk API or through Data Loader tool. I need to have the field "Date/Time Opened" under the new cases I am creating to have the same date that it had in our previous system. The issue is, when the case is generated the Date/Time Opened is set by SalesForce to the date the case is created in SalesForce. I understand that there is no direct way to alter this directly. However...

Is there a backdoor solution to this problem? I need the display under Accounts -> [Account] -> Cases to list the case dates under "Date Opened" correctly as it relates to our historical data. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted support?   I know they will allow you to modify audit fields (createDate, lastModifiedDate, etc) for migration.   You can load to these fields using data loader.

NOTE: **Date/Time Opened** is the label for **CreatedDate** on the Case Object.

Requesing Audit Fields to be writable with Support will allow you to import your own values for CreatedDate (insert only, not update).

Link below:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Considerations-before-having-Create-Audit-Fields-enabled&language=en_US